# Select rows in Dataframe where one column's value is in another list column

Tags: dataframe, pandas

I'm trying the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [[1,2], [3,4], [3,2]]})
df
     col1    col2
0     1      [1, 2]
1     2      [3, 4]
2     3      [3, 2]
```

and I would like to select rows where `col1` value is in `col2` list

```
df[df.col1.isin(df.col2)]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []
```

But I get the empty df. Why does the `isin` function doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the `isin` function doesn't work?

[`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) takes a set or list. When you call:

```py
df.col1.isin(some_set_or_list)
```

- It just tests if each value of `col1` is in the entire `some_set_or_list`, which in this case is `[[1,2],[3,4],[3,2]]`.
- It does *not* test if `col1[0]` is in `some_set_or_list[0]`, if `col1[1]` is in `some_set_or_list[1]`, etc. In fact `some_set_or_list` can be a totally different length than `col1`.

For example if `col1`'s first value were `[3,4]` instead:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[3,4],2,3], 'col2': [[1,2], [3,4], [3,2]]})

#      col1    col2
# 0  [3, 4]  [1, 2]
# 1       2  [3, 4]
# 2       3  [3, 2]
```

`isin` would give you `True` for the first row since `[3,4]` is *somewhere* in `col2` as a whole (*not* element-wise):

```py
df.col1.isin(df.col2)

# 0     True
# 1    False
# 2    False
# Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

What you're actually trying to do is a row-wise test, which is what [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68664856/13138364) does:

```py
df.apply(lambda row: row.col1 in row.col2, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple case of `apply(axis=1)` with required condition to return a boolean that can then be used as a mask in `loc[]`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [[1,2], [3,4], [3,2]]})

df.loc[df.apply(lambda r: r["col1"] in r["col2"], axis=1)]
```

#### output

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | [1, 2] |
| 2 | 3 | [3, 2] |